# Parsing XML Data with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I am new to LINQ. I need to return the id with the correct price information for today's date for each MPrice.

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<Pricing>
<MPrice>
    <Id>0079</Id>
      <Price>
        <Price>31.25</Price>
        <StartDt>2009-8-01</StartDt>
        <EndDt>2009-08-26</EndDt>
      </Price>
      <Price>
        <ListPrice>131.25</ListPrice>
        <StartDt>2009-08-26</StartDt>
        <EndDt>9999-12-31</EndDt>
       </Price>
   </MPrice>
   <MPrice>
    <Id>0081</Id>
      <Price>
        <Price>131.25</Price>
        <StartDt>2009-8-01</StartDt>
        <EndDt>2009-08-26</EndDt>
      </Price>
      <Price>
        <ListPrice>231.25</ListPrice>
        <StartDt>2009-08-26</StartDt>
        <EndDt>9999-12-31</EndDt>
       </Price>
   </MPrice> 
</Pricing>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String xml = @"<Pricing>
            <MPrice>
                <Id>0079</Id>
                <Price>
                <Price>31.25</Price>
                <StartDt>2009-8-01</StartDt>
                <EndDt>2009-08-26</EndDt>
                </Price>
                <Price>
                <ListPrice>131.25</ListPrice>
                <StartDt>2009-08-26</StartDt>
                <EndDt>9999-12-31</EndDt>
                </Price>
            </MPrice>
           </Pricing>";

        var priceInfo = from e in XElement.Parse(xml).Elements("MPrice").Elements("Price")
                let start = DateTime.Parse(e.Descendants("StartDt").FirstOrDefault().Value)
                let end = DateTime.Parse(e.Descendants("EndDt").FirstOrDefault().Value)
                where start < DateTime.Now && end > DateTime.Now
                select new { Id = e.Parent.Element("Id").Value, ListPrice = e.Element("ListPrice").Value };

        Console.WriteLine(priceInfo.FirstOrDefault().Id);
        Console.WriteLine(priceInfo.FirstOrDefault().ListPrice);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0079
131.25
```

Please note that there needs to be much more error checking than this example provides.  I would specifically add checking around the parsing of the datetime (perhaps by using a function that wraps `DateTime.TryParseExact`).

**Edit:** If you want to use an `XDocument` instead of an `XElement` you will need to make a subtle change to the query (notice the usage of the `Descendants` method instead of the `Elements` method):

```
var priceInfo = from e in XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("MPrice").Elements("Price")
        let start = DateTime.Parse(e.Descendants("StartDt").FirstOrDefault().Value)
        let end = DateTime.Parse(e.Descendants("EndDt").FirstOrDefault().Value)
        where start < DateTime.Now && end > DateTime.Now
        select new { Id = e.Parent.Element("Id").Value, ListPrice = e.Element("ListPrice").Value };
```

Remember that you don't need to use an `XDocument` unless you are working with the XML as a true document.  In most cases, the `XElement` type is sufficient.

**Edit #2:** If you want to load the `XDocument` from disk then use this approach:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"d:\test.xml");

        var priceInfo = from e in document.Descendants("MPrice").Elements("Price")
                let start = DateTime.Parse(e.Descendants("StartDt").FirstOrDefault().Value)
                let end = DateTime.Parse(e.Descendants("EndDt").FirstOrDefault().Value)
                where start < DateTime.Now && end > DateTime.Now
                select new { Id = e.Parent.Element("Id").Value, ListPrice = e.Element("ListPrice").Value };

        Console.WriteLine(priceInfo.FirstOrDefault().Id);
        Console.WriteLine(priceInfo.FirstOrDefault().ListPrice);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do the same parsing using XDocument instead of XElement?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work.  I am using:
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("my.xml");

Now when I call the :
    XDocument.Parse(xml).Descendants("MPrice").Elements("Price")
I receive an error with not converted XDocument to string.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you have already loaded the XML into the `XDocument` then you don't need to call `XDocument.Parse`.  I will edit again to demonstrate how to do it with an XML file on disk.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. The project is almost completed and I learned a few new things.   Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
string id = yourDocument
                .Descendants("Pricing")
                .Descendants<XElement>("MPrice")
                .Where<XElement>(i => i.Descendants("Price")
                                        .Descendants<XElement>("StartDt")
                                        .Select<XElement, DateTime>(s => DateTime.Parse(s.Value))
                                        .FirstOrDefault<DateTime>().Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                .Select<XElement, string>(i => i.Descendants("Id").FirstOrDefault<XElement>().Value)
                .FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

This should work assuming that the id is a string.  You can make it an int.

You should do some checks to make sure the date is correct etc.. . . , but this is a quick example that should work for given Xml example if Start Date is changed to 2009-9-03 or the current dates date.